# Visualize a tensor (video) in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

While training my nets, I want to visualize video of each epoch.
Until now I made a function that gets my tensor (size: [3, 32, 64,64] - 3 batch size, 32 frames, 64X64 resolution).
I want to visualize some videos as a grid.
I tried to use

```
import torch
import torchvision.utils as vutils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import scipy.misc

def show(img):
   npimg = img.numpy()
   plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1,2,0))interpolation='nearest')

video = torch.randn(3,32,64,64)
grid = vutils.make_grid(video)
show(grid) # here to use save_img func
```

But it failed. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: You could use OpenCV to display the images one by one, and with a little bit of delay after each image, you can see a video. I think you can find the required OpenCV library and functions by googling a bit.

Comment: Also, you didn't mention how your code 'failed'. Error? or did you not see the images? If you saw only the last image, you need to put some delay after showing each image, so you can see each image, and it will look like a video.

Comment: I can display the video but i want to display a grid of video at once. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def show(img):
   npimg = img.numpy()
   plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1,2,0)), interpolation='nearest')

video = torch.randn(32,3,64,64)
grid = vutils.make_grid(video)
show(grid) # here to use save_img func
```

You forgot the comma separating the arguments of plt.imshow().
I swap the frame and channel dimensions. I think a video can be represented as a tensor of shape [#of_frames, #of_channels, hight, width].